# What's the point of destructuring declarations in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have come across the concept called *destructuring declarations* - when you can return multiple values from a function at once. It seems very convenient, but at the same time it looks like a tricky workaround. Each time when I think about that feature in Java, I understand that it's a hole in my architecture - there should probably be a class then, not just a couple of variables.

What do you think?

Comment: Returning 2 things from a function is only one corner use case. The feature itself is used in many more situations, and it has proved to be useful and maintainable.

Comment: "there should probably be a class there" - if all you have is j̶a̶v̶a̶ a hammer, then everything looks like c̶l̶a̶s̶s̶e̶s̶ nails. Another language - different idioms. Also, what @voddan said.

Comment: Destructuring declarations do need a class in Kotlin. I think the main purpose of it is to provide simplicity instead of multiple return values. Most of the use cases are demonstrated in the [official doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html).

Comment: @GKh, I have added an answer to your question, I hope that broadens your knowledge :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The concept allows having classes that clearly identify a few of their primary properties, the *components*.

Then you can access these components by using a destructuring declaration, without syntactic noise of accessing the properties.

Compare:

```
 val point = clickEvent.getPointOnScreen()
 val x = point.xCoordinate
 val y = point.yCoordinate
 // Use `x` and `y` in some calculations
```

and, assuming that the type has `component1` and `component2`, just:

```
 val (x, y) = clickEvent.getPointOnScreen()
```

Basically, it is not necessary to use this sort of syntactic sugar, and the concept itself does not harm any of the abstractions, it only provides a convenient way to access properties of a class instance in some cases when you don't need the instance itself.

Another example is working with map entries, e.g:

```
for ((key, value) in myMap) { /* ... */ }
```

There's still a `Map.Entry<K, V>` behind the `(key, value)` destructuring, and you can replace it by `for (entry in myMap) ...`, but usually it's the two properties that you need. This is where destructuring saves you from a little syntactic noise.

Comment: Use with caution, if you refactor by interchanging the two variables xCoordinate and yCoordinate in your object -> component1 and component2 will be switched -> your ```val (x, y)``` will be in fact ```val (y, x)``` and here you are with bugs all over the place.

Comment: Using the ctrl+f6 or cmd+f6 refactoring tool handles this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define componentN function as extension for non data classes like this:

```
operator fun Location.component1() = latitude
operator fun Location.component2() = longitude
```

and when you want to process on list of locations, you can write this:

```
for ((lat, lon) in locations) {
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What's the point of destructuring declarations in Kotlin?

Structuring, or construction, is creating an object from values in different variables. Destructuring is the opposite, to extract values into variables from within an existing object.

Part of the Kotlin philosophy is to be concise since the simpler and more concise the code is, the faster you’ll understand what’s going on. Destructuring improves readability which is part of being concise. Compare the following two snippets (let's consider the class [`Triple`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-triple/))

**Without using destructuring**

```kotlin
fun getFullName() = Triple("Thomas", "Alva", "Edison")
val result = getFullName()
val first = result.first
val middle = result.second
val last = result.third
```

**Using destructuring**

```kotlin
fun getFullName() = Triple("Thomas", "Alva", "Edison")
val (first, middle, last) = getFullName()
```

It is also possible to take advantage of destructuring to extract `key` and `value` from [`Map`'s entries](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/-entry/).

```kotlin
for ((key, value) in aMap) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Destructuring is the most useful when dealing with built-in data structures. Their fields have names making sense in the context of a data structure (handy when you're writing your own hashmap), but completely cryptic when you're dealing with the data contained there (which is 100% of the time, nobody writes their own hashmaps). Eg. `Pair` with it's `first` and `second` or `Map.Entry` with `key` and `value`.

Consider transforming `Map` values:

```
    val myMap = mapOf("apples" to 0, "oranges" to 1, "bananas" to 2)

    myMap
        .asIterable()
        .filter { it.value > 0 }
        .sortedBy { it.key.length }
        .joinToString(prefix = "We have ", postfix = " in the warehouse") {
            "{$it.value} of ${it.key}"
        }
```

To make it readable, you'd have to define intermediate variables:

```
    myMap
        .asIterable()
        .filter {
            val count = it.value
            count > 0
        }
        .sortedBy {
            val fruit = it.key
            fruit.length
        }
        .joinToString(prefix = "We have ", postfix = " in the warehouse") {
            val count = it.value
            val fruit = it.key
            "$count of $fruit"
        }
```

Now it's readable, but at what cost?!?

Destructuring makes this cost more beareable:

```
    myMap
        .asIterable()
        .filter { (fruit, count) -> count > 0 }
        .sortedBy { (fruit, count) -> fruit.length }
        .joinToString(prefix = "We have ", postfix = " in the warehouse") { (fruit, count) ->
            "$count of $fruit"
        }
```

That's the point.